# Compile two layers by new added points or updated attribute

Tags: qgis, point, qgis-modeler

I have two point layers:

1. Layer A and
2. layer B (which is the copy of Layer A), so they have same data at the beginning.

Now I`d like to make some changes in layer B and sometimes add another point to layer B.

Afterwards (for example one time per week) I would like to add all changes and new points of Layer B to the original layer A.

To select the new changes I added a **date** to the attributes of both Layers, that updates automatically when changes were made (**now()**).

So now I just need a query that does select the new points of layer B (which not already exist in layer A) and select those fields of layer B, which are newer than the ones in layer A by **date**.